# Add url to multiple markers to google map in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add a google map to wordpress, with multiple markers, and I want each marker to be a link to a url. 
I don't know much about java and php so I did a lot of researches and the only method that's working is this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

var locations = [
      ['Rome', 41.9100711,12.5359979, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.9100711,12.5359979),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
    clickable: true,

      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
```

But I don't know how to add a url for each location. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like @incredible answer,
I'll provide a little code snippet, may be a little help for you..

```js
var locations = [
    ['Rome', 41.9100711, 12.5359979, 4,"http://google.co.id/"],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5,"http://google.co.id/"],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3,"http://google.co.id/"],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2,"http://google.co.id/"],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1,"http://google.co.id/"]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.9100711, 12.5359979),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        clickable: true,
        url:locations[i][4]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            window.location.href = marker.url;
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map" style="width:600px; height:450px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add url as 4th parameter to your locations array. For example:

```
var locations = [
      ['Rome', 41.9100711,12.5359979, 4, 'example.com'],
...
];
```

And when you creating Marker object, put it as url param. e.g.:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        clickable: true,
        url: locations[i][4]});
```

And in the event listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    window.location.href = this.url;
    ...
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work, the map simply disappeared

Comment: Sorry, @giuliomaione. I gave only some parts of code. Not all solution:)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what I did in location ROME, if that  works, do the same to rest.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

var locations = [
      ["<a href='#'>Rome</a>", 41.9100711,12.5359979, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.9100711,12.5359979),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
    clickable: true,

      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it added a link in the info box (and it can be useful that way too), but I want the marker itself to be a link...so when I click on the marker, it doesn't open the infobox, but links me directly at the url.